# Copy Same Cell and Paste each time to next cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have wrote this code which copies the `Sheet2.Range("B4")` and Paste it into `Sheet3.Range("B4")`.

I have been striving to find that how upon running the code again will paste `Sheet2.Range("B4")` into the next cell of `Sheet3.Range("B4")` that would be `C4`, then upon running the code again to `D4` then `E4`. One by one.

So the logic will be each time i have to run the code to paste the value into next cell.

```
Sub copyPasteValues()
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim sht3 As Worksheet

Set sht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set sht3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

sht2.Cells(4, 2).copy
sht3.Cells(4, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you overwriting anything in sheet 3 or pasting into blank cells?

Comment: Pasting into blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the last used column on sheet 3 in row 4 and add one.

Something like this:

```
Sub copyPasteValues()
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim sht3 As Worksheet

Dim col As Long

Set sht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set sht3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

col = sht3.Cells(4, sht3.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
if col = 3 then
    sht2.Cells(5, 4).Copy
else
    sht2.Cells(4, 2).Copy
end if
sht3.Cells(4, col).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

If you need it to stop at column I then do:

```
if col = 3 then
    sht2.Cells(5, 4).Copy
elseif col <= 9 then
    sht2.Cells(4, 2).Copy
else
    exit sub
end if
```

Comment: Thank you but it does not paste to next cell if i run the code again

Comment: Thank you its working now i just changed it sht2.Cells(4, 2).Copy. thank you very much

Comment: Ahh sorry didn't realize you always wanted the sht2 cell to remain the same.

Comment: I need one more favor that @Warcupine if it does not bother you. When i run the code it paste the Sheet2.Range("B4") into Sheet3.Range("B4") i want that if i run the code again it should paste the Sheet2.Range("D5") into Sheet3.Range("C4") then again normal process that was Sheet2.Range("B4") into Sheet3.Range("D4"), then e4, then f4 and so on

Comment: So even column numbers on sheet3 get `sheet2.range("B4")` and odd column numbers get `sheet2.range("D5")`?

Comment: I have added a picture above which expresses that what i want i run the code 8th time in the above picture where 1st time code paste B4 2nd time paste D4 then B4, B4, B4 and B4 value upon running the code again over again

Comment: What do you mean for Even and odd number.

Comment: If `Sht3.Range("B4") = Sht2.Range("B4")`, `Sht3.Range("C4") = Sht2.Range("D5")`, `Sht3.Range("D4") = Sht2.Range("B4")`, `Sht3.Range("E4") = Sht2.Range("D5")` So if the column index is even it would get from B4 and if the index is odd it would get from D5. Your picture clarified.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was not able to understand this thing before.

Comment: Thank you very very much @Warcupine